# Are there any code analysis tools to detect the == operator when it's comparing specific types?

Tags: c#, .net, operators, code-analysis

In a legacy code-base, for many technical reasons, we are replacing parameters that have previously been of a base class type to an interface type.  For example:

```
public interface IDomainObject { int Id { get; } }

public abstract class BaseDomainObject : IDomainObject
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        var domainObj = obj as BaseDomainObject;
        return domainObj != null && Id.Equals(domainObj.Id);
    }
    public static bool operator ==(BaseDomainObject x, BaseDomainObject y)
    {
        return !ReferenceEquals(x, null) && !ReferenceEquals(y, null) && x.Equals(y);
    }
    public static bool operator !=(BaseDomainObject x, BaseDomainObject y)
    {
        return !(x == y);
    }
}

public class MyDomainObject : BaseDomainObject
{
    public MyDomainObject(int id) { Id = id; }
    ...
}
```

So everywhere in code, where we would previously have a variable of type *BaseDomainObject* we now have one of type *IDomainObject*. However, we are running into problems with the '==' operator--it doesn't work with interfaces.  For all interface types, the '==' operator just falls back to *ReferenceEquals()*.

The following code demonstrates the problem:

```
    // Old style
    BaseDomainObject baseobj1A = new MyDomainObject(1);
    BaseDomainObject baseobj1B = new MyDomainObject(1);
    BaseDomainObject baseobj2 = new MyDomainObject(2);

    Assert.IsTrue(baseobj1A != baseobj2);
    Assert.IsTrue(baseobj1A == baseobj1B); // Succeeds

    // New style
    IDomainObject iobj1A = new MyDomainObject(1);
    IDomainObject iobj1B = new MyDomainObject(1);
    IDomainObject iobj2 = new MyDomainObject(2);

    Assert.IsTrue(iobj1A != iobj2);
    Assert.IsTrue(iobj1A == iobj1B); // Fails
```

Going back to using a base class is not an option--our interface is generic co-variant (similar to *IDomainObject<out T>*)which is necessary for the polymorphic behavior that we need.  Ideally we would just replace all of the '==' with *.Equals()*.  However, our codebase is huge, and finding all of the '==' operators that we care about would be a mammoth task.

One thought was that we could write an FxCop rule that would flag all occurrences of a variable of a certain interface type (ie, *IDomainObject*) used in an '==' comparison.  But this didn't work--FxCop doesn't support this.  Another thought was to write our own code analysis tool that just checks for this case, but that would be time consuming.

So the question is, is there already some kind of code analysis tool out there that we could use to find these '==' occurrences?

Comment: You can try tool like R# by jetbrains.com to find all type usages. It support plugins and you can add required functionality.

Comment: Nope, find usages doesn't find them.

Comment: Why do you say that FxCop does not support this?  Have you actually tried creating a custom FxCop rule that would look for inappropriate equality verifications against instances of your target interface(s)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use custom search patterns with ReSharper to do things like this.

You could also consider doing this the "old fashioned way". Change all the references, then fix the compilation errors.

Answer (score 0):

If Visual Studio's "Find all references" fails to find all usages of the specific implementation of `==`, I'm pretty sure Resharper's "Find Usages" will find them without a problem.